# what does the operator& return type mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading, iostream, function-declaration

So from my knowledge,

```
istream& operator >> (istream &in, int &n);
```

is the declaration for how >> works (or to overload it in some way)

But I'm confused on this "function's" return type, "istream&".

If I do something like cin >> x; that means I'm putting in the reference to x, but I don't understand the return type istream &, and the parameter "in".

What would this function look like defined? what IS "in"? And what is it actually RETURNING? Because cin >> x does really do anything but take in an input so why does it have to return anything?

Thanks!

Comment: it's a reference to an `istream`. - and `istream& operator >> (istream &in, int &n);` means `n` will be modified - as opposed to `const <type>&n`

Comment: Returning a reference to the stream is what allows constructs like `cin >> x >> y`

Comment: There is no "`&operator`" as your title implies. The function name is `operator >>` (two tokens) and `&` is an unrelated token used to indicate a reference type. So `&operator` is not a thing.

Comment: @curiousguy Well spotted - I changed it

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see no address operator in your code.

Comment: @curiousguy I only changed `&operator` to `operator&` - It was my "aha" to your comment. - in OP:s question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is no `operator&`, but `operator>>`

Comment: @curiousguy The question was: "what does the the &operator return type mean?" - I only changed it to "what does the the operator& return type mean?" - and I did as a reaction to you comment. Maybe not the correct reason, but still ok I think.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code has `istream& operator >> ` which can be written with the characters `&operator` together as anyway it's two separate token. **The OP should clarify whether there is any address of operator!**

Comment: We're not talking about the same thing. I changed the topic that you objected to. That's it.

Comment: @curiousguy - are we settled or is there still some misconception of what my correction of the question was about?

Comment: @TedLyngmo The title no at least makes sense in itself, as `operator&` is a thing unlike `&operator`, but it may not reflect the OP's intent; I guessed that he wrote `&operator` in the title because these two tokens appear together in his code. He may have meant something like `&operator>>(...)`.

Comment: Oh, if I changed OP:s intent - I apologize. I did not receive that comment from OP earlier.

Comment: @curiousguy Are you ok with my edit if OP is?

Comment: @TedLyngmo If that was the OP question, I'm OK with your edit but I think the OP is confused about syntax. It's the OP turn to answer now!

Comment: Hey guys, to be honest I'm pretty new to c++ so I didn't follow that whole interaction, but my question just really had to do with just the type of what this "function" returned, I didn't understand how this operator overloading worked as a whole, without focusing too much on the "reference" & and where it goes. I was more worried about what the function did and looked out. Thanks!
@curiousguy

Comment: @TedLyngmo ^^, idk why I can't notify both of you

Comment: @ming You need to learn to decipher the surprising but internally consistant C/C++ principe of declaring stuff (variables or functions). This is called a **declarator**: `& operator >> (istream &in, int &n)`. See, the `&` is part of it, but not of the name of the function which is just `operator >>`. It reads: calling `operator >>` with a modifiable lvalue of `istream` and one of `int` returns formally a reference, that is, gives an lvalue. An lvalue is an expression that refers to an identified object.

Comment: Yeah our teacher mentioned lvalues but didn't really go into them much so it confuses me a little. Doesn't the & mean reference? So "operator >>" is the name of the function and "istream&" is the return type then? In that case I don't really understand & here. And when you say that an lvalue is an expression that refers to an identified object, that just means that on the left is basically anything but the right side of the "=" has to have an address? That's kind of what I took away from class.. @curiousguy

Comment: @ming If you know lvalues, **you can't understand the meaning and purpose of references.** The & declares a reference, a use of a function "returning a reference" is a lvalue. It's as if the function was returning the "name" or designation of an object.

Answer (score 2):

The standard implementation of operator >> would return a reference to the istream &in parameter which means it returns the exact same object.

This is for convenience so you can write code like: `cin >> x >> y;`

The compiler will take what is on the **left** side of the operator and put in the **first** parameter and the **right** in the **second**.
cin >> x >> y will translate into `operator>>( (operator>>(cin, x), y );`

This will first add x to the stream and use the return, the stream itself, and write y to that.

Answer (score 0):

It means it's a *pass-thru* in this particualar case (and many others). It's a contract to return something sensible with the input given. Returning `is` is the sensible thing since it makes constructs like:

`stream >> variableA >> variableB >> variableC`

possible. That's because `stream >> variableA` returns `stream` an so do the other operations.

Comment: Ohhh right, I forgot that there were different outputs streams, so "stream" as in your example would be like "cout" or "outfile" right?

And so does that mean that technically if we pass in cin, we can return outfile?

And say that we double every integer n we pass in. Then how does that new n get returned as well if the only thing we're being returned is an output stream? Like if we put in parameters, what we get in return is just the stream we put in (ex. cin) or a new stream (outfile)

Comment: @ming Much so -.it's a very open language, but very picky with what it accepts :-)

Comment: @ming The canonical impl of all read/write operators (op<< op>>) is `return lhs;` (for a non member) or `return *this;` (for a member)

Answer (score 0):

If the function,

```
istream& operator >> (istream &in, int &n);
```

returned, instead,

```
istream operator >>....
```

Then, things get complicated. In a worst-case scenario, every invocation of `>>` would copy the stream object and return the copy, which would then be copied and stored in the caller's stack, followed by calls to destructors of all those things that were copied, special circumstances excepted.

By returning a reference, we can do things like chaining:

```
a << b << "Yo!" << c << "Wassup?" << endl;
```

...without all of that nonsense.

`&` means "reference," which is essentially a pointer with stronger compile-time checking and nicer syntax.

Comment: Internally it's implemented as a ptr, but for the syntax and semantic POV, it isn't. The expression using a reference refers to the object not its address.

Comment: OK... My previous non proofread comment deleted in shame, pls do the same.